# Managing multiple projects in circleCI

Tags: reactjs, git, web, circleci

I'm currently writing a circleCI script for a project. This folder has multiple projects within it, each with their respective build and deploy scripts.

My question is, how do I manage the multiple projects, do I need a `.circleci` folder within each project or can I use a single `yml` script to handle the sub directories.

My current script `cd` into the sub directory in each run step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in one, by having multiple items under `jobs`. The default job must be called `build` but you can call the others whatever you like. Then you can `cd` into the appropriate directory inside each job, or add the directory name to your command arguments as you see fit. From [the docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs):

> A run is comprised of one or more named jobs. Jobs are specified in the `jobs` map, see [Sample 2.0 config.yml](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config/) for two examples of a `job` map. The name of the job is the key in the map, and the value is a map describing the job.
>
> ...
>
> If you are **not** using workflows, the `jobs` map must contain a job named `build`. This `build` job is the default entry-point for a run that is triggered by a push to your VCS provider. It is possible to then specify additional jobs and run them using the CircleCI API.

Elsewhere, a repo I contribute to has a [working example of this](https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-auth-server/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml):

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      # ...

  build-oauth:
    steps:
      # ...
```

Comment: I understand using `jobs`, how do I specify the working directory for each job. Is that possible?

Comment: You can `cd` into the appropriate directory in the steps for each job, or you can edit the steps so that the arguments for commands get prefixed with the appropriate directory name. Whichever is preferable.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that. Thanks